# PEP8 best docstring practice when function has multiple different return

Tags: python, function, pep8, docstring

I have the following function:

```
def eg_fun(eg:int):
    """example function
    """
   
    if eg > 2:
        return 2, 4
    else:
        return 'no', None
```

In the function definition how I can put different returning Tuple?

If I would have a single return type I writing:  `def eg_fun(eg:int) -> Tuple[int, int]:`

But in this case I have two different return type, the first one is `Tuple[int, int]` while the second one is `Tuple[str, None]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running python 3.10 `-> Tuple[int, int] | Tuple [str, None]` should work

Comment: I'm using python 3.9

Comment: Then you should use `Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[str, None]]`.